# Server-side item does not appear on visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I'm creating a project for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 following this tutorial:
[Getting Started - Create a controller](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html#create-a-controller). However, I've not found the "Server-side" item because there's only "Client-side".

[image: Visual studio 2015]

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial seems to be outdated. 
On VS 2015 you can add a new MVC Controller.

To use the MVC Controller template:
 - Right click in your proyect -> Add -> New Item -> `ASP.NET` ->`MVC Controller Class`

To use an empy class template:
 - Right click in your proyect -> Add -> New Item -> `Code` -> `Class`

[image]

According to [.NET site](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows), you should have installed:

- [Visual Studio 2015 Update 3](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691129)
- [.NET Core 1.0.0 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817245)